# IIS is not sending digital signature property in downloaded static Exe file

Tags: iis-8

I signed my .exe file and deployed on IIS web server.I can see server Exe file contains digital signature but when I download this file on my local machine using static IIS URL, the downloaded file is missing digital signature.

I checked on other web server (Production Server) the IIS sends digital signature property with downloaded file. I am not getting what IIS setting is missing on my server.

looks like some IIS setting will do a trick may be MIME type ? Can any one please help on this ?

Comment: If you have a good server and a bad one, why cannot you ask the server administrators to compare the settings? No one can guess that out across the internet for you.

Comment: How did you deploy the .exe file? What kind of project is it?

Comment: I manually copied this file on server. The Exe is built using Delphi language. Now, I copied same Exe on other test server and downloaded Exe file contains digital signature, I did not set any IIS setting on new test server. Looks like the IIS is not a culprit, might be some server's Firewall / group policy settings creating this issue.